# How can I sovle "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError：com/ctc/wstx/io/InputBootstrapper"

Tags: java, hadoop, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm a pure newbie to hadoop and java.I would be very grateful if you could help me.

I now have **VSCODE** started in **WSL**, I have configured pseudo-distributed **Hadoop** in WSL, and now I want to run a sample program for Java in VSCODE under WSL, I have included the reference libraries I need into this project, and I have put several related configuration files of Hadoop into the project, but I have been experiencing this problem.

This problem seems to have been present with statements **Configuration conf = new Configuration()**;

the wrong information are as followed:

```
liu@liu:~/bigdata/proj1$  cd /home/liu/bigdata/proj1 ; /usr/bin/env /usr/local/jdk8/bin/java -cp /tmp/cp_9uebk944mttbxgu829j50i3s5.jar CopyFromLocalFile 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ctc/wstx/io/InputBootstrapper
        at CopyFromLocalFile.main(CopyFromLocalFile.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ctc.wstx.io.InputBootstrapper
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 1 more
```

is it a question that related to WSL？Why do I get this error after I have included all the library files I should have?

How do I fix this?please help,thanks~

1. I set up the .vscode file
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9upKe.png)

task.json

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "hadoop - start service",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "start-all.sh",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "group": "build"
    },
    {
        "label": "hadoop - build & run",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "mkdir /tmp/a2f2ed || : && javac -cp $(hadoop classpath) -d /tmp/a2f2ed ${file} && jar -cvf bin/test.jar -C /tmp/a2f2ed . && rm -rf /tmp/a2f2ed || :&& hdfs dfs -rm -r /input || : && hdfs dfs -put input / && hdfs dfs -rm -r /output || :&& hadoop jar bin/test.jar ${fileBasenameNoExtension} /input /output && hdfs dfs -cat /output/*",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "group": "build"
    },
    {
        "label": "hadoop - stop service",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "stop-all.sh",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "group": "build"
    },
]
}
```

setting.json

```
{
    "java.project.sourcePaths": ["src"],
    "java.project.outputPath": "bin",
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "lib/**/*.jar",
        "/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.3.0.jar",
        "/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-3.3.0.jar",
        "/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.3.0.jar",
        "/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-3.3.0.jar",
        "/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.2.4.jar",
        "/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-3.2.4.jar",
        "/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar",
        "/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.2.4.jar",
        "/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-3.2.4.jar",
        "/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-kms-3.2.4.jar",
        "/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-3.2.4.jar",
        "/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-uploader-3.2.4.jar"
    ]
}
```

2.the reference libraries I used

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcSJQ.png)

3.I Write the src files
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3Gwg.png)

the source java code are as followed:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
public class CopyFromLocalFile {
    /**
        * 判断路径是否存在
     */
    public static boolean test(Configuration conf, String path) {
           try (FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf)) {
               return fs.exists(new Path(path));  
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               return false;
           }
       }
     
       /**
        * 复制文件到指定路径 若路径已存在，则进行覆盖
        */
       public static void copyFromLocalFile(Configuration conf,
               String localFilePath, String remoteFilePath) {
           Path localPath = new Path(localFilePath);
           Path remotePath = new Path(remoteFilePath);
           try (FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf)) {
               /* fs.copyFromLocalFile 第一个参数表示是否删除源文件，第二个参数表示是否覆盖 */
               fs.copyFromLocalFile(false, true, localPath, remotePath);
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
     
       }
     
       /**
        * 追加文件内容
        */
       public static void appendToFile(Configuration conf, String localFilePath,
               String remoteFilePath) {
           Path remotePath = new Path(remoteFilePath);
           try (FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
                   FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(localFilePath);) {
               FSDataOutputStream out = fs.append(remotePath);
               byte[] data = new byte[1024];
               int read = -1;
               while ((read = in.read(data)) > 0) {
                   out.write(data, 0, read);
               }
               out.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
     
       /**
        * 主函数
        */
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Configuration conf = new Configuration();
           conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:9000");
           String localFilePath = "/usr/local/hadoop/text.txt"; // 本地路径
           String remoteFilePath = "/user/hadoop/file/text.txt"; // HDFS路径
           // String choice = "append"; // 若文件存在则追加到文件末尾
           String choice = "overwrite"; // 若文件存在则覆盖
     
           try {
               /* 判断文件是否存在 */
               boolean fileExists = false;
               if (CopyFromLocalFile.test(conf, remoteFilePath)) {
                   fileExists = true;
                   System.out.println(remoteFilePath + " 已存在.");
               } else {
                   System.out.println(remoteFilePath + " 不存在.");
               }
               /* 进行处理 */
               if (!fileExists) { // 文件不存在，则上传
                   CopyFromLocalFile.copyFromLocalFile(conf, localFilePath,
                           remoteFilePath);
                   System.out.println(localFilePath + " 已上传至 " + remoteFilePath);
               } else if (choice.equals("overwrite")) { // 选择覆盖
                   CopyFromLocalFile.copyFromLocalFile(conf, localFilePath,
                           remoteFilePath);
                   System.out.println(localFilePath + " 已覆盖 " + remoteFilePath);
               } else if (choice.equals("append")) { // 选择追加
                   CopyFromLocalFile.appendToFile(conf, localFilePath,
                           remoteFilePath);
                   System.out.println(localFilePath + " 已追加至 " + remoteFilePath);
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use maven to build this from very begining,then the problem will be sovled